# Error comparing integer with string in MysQL query (1 = '1sk')

Tags: mysql, sql, type-conversion

When I run this query, why do I have that a number is equal to a `varchar`?

```
select 1='sk', 1=1, 1='1sk', 0='sk', 9='9sk', 90='90ss' from dual
```

[image: Example]

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: You cannot "disable" this feature.  Instead, you should just use the correct types when making comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

In such scenarios, MySql takes the leading digits in a string and converts them to a number, and ignores everything form the point it hits a character that isn't a digit.

Instead, you could explicitly cast your numbers to strings:

```
MariaDB [db]> SELECT 1='1sk', CAST(1 AS CHAR)='1sk';
+---------+-----------------------+
| 1='1sk' | CAST(1 AS CHAR)='1sk' |
+---------+-----------------------+
|       1 |                     0 |
+---------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```